# Matching a user's selection with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I've read many previous questions on regexs' and I've gone through the documentation for them on the python website. Ive also successfully used them in the past but i cannot get them to work in this example, that's why I'm posting now.

I'm trying to make a vending machine in python and so far come up with this code for displaying and selecting which product you want to buy. (obviously its a bit crude at the moment :) )

However I've run into a problem with the regular expressions. I want to make sure that only numbers 1 - 5 can be entered and if not it continues to ask for the input.

What I've currently tried:

Removing all regexs' and adding an else on the end. This works for numbers not 1-5 but gives back an error when I type a character/letter in. So I really want to use a regex for this which limits only 1-5 being entered and no letters.

```
products = ["MarsBar:","Twix:","DoubleDecker:","Flake:","Revels:"]
prices = ["£1.00","£0.90","£1.20","£1.10","£1.30"]

for counter in range(4): print (counter + 1, products[counter],prices[counter])
#___________________________________________________________________________________
valid1 = 0
import re
while valid1 == 0:
    choice = (input("Please enter your choice between 1 and 5..."))
    valid = 1
    if not re.match("^[1-5]*$", choice):
        print("must be valid")
        valid1 = 0
    if choice == 1:
        valid1 = 1
        print (products[0])
    elif choice == 2:
        valid1 = 1
        print (products[1])
    elif choice == 3:
        valid1 = 1
        print (products[2])
    elif choice == 4:
        valid1 = 1
        print (products[3])
    elif choice == 5:
        valid1 = 1
        print (products[4])

print("Thankyou")
```

Comment: Souldn't that be `^[1-5]+$` ?

Comment: Why would you not use a dictionary instead of 2 lists?

Comment: I was advised not to for now :)

Comment: @user3450018 I demonstrated how to use a dictionary in my answer below. You should take a look at it even if you can't use it.

Comment: Yes i think i will implement it into my own code. Thankyou :)

Comment: OP, I was the first person to post you a correct implementation. It's also more compact code and avoids risking the exception from `int()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions here is like using a supersonic jet to go to work. The code you posted shows that you're starting out with programming, and regular expressions are complicated beasts. You should avoid them until you feel more comfortable.

Try using simpler constructs:

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    choice = input(...)
    valid  = choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')

print products[int(choice) - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, this one works well for me :) and adam it doesnt let 1, 12, 123 etc through ???

Comment: @user3450018 upside down has since fixed that edge-case :) Originally it was `if choice in '12345'` which smci correctly noted in his own comments will fail on `'123'` since `'123' in '12345' == True`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good application for Regex, first of all. If it were, you would use `[^12345]`, but it's not, so we won't do that. Instead, do this:

```
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("choice between 1-5: "))
        if choice not in range(1,6):
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid value")
    else:
        break
```

This is better because `choice` is now an int, you don't have to set `valid1` at all, just reuse choice. Also since they correspond to the indexes you're returning, just use the value rather than `if/elif` checking them all.

```
print(products[choice-1])
```

Comment: My answer is equivalent but only 6 lines long instead of 9, and clearer. Avoid risking throwing the exception in the first place!

Comment: @smci Your answer is also explicitly WRONG right now. Also, why is it a "risk" to throw an exception I immediately catch? If the user gives an input that's "exceptional," you should use exceptions to catch that. That's just Python...

Comment: @smci It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission

Comment: @Adam-Smith. No it's not. I clearly said my approach is not to call `int()` on the string. Leave it a string.

Comment: @IanAuld no, not in this case. You don't benefit at all from casting to int when you could have performed the test more compactly on the string.

Comment: @smci There is nothing wrong with catching exceptions, especially if you plan for them to be there.

Comment: @IanAuld Yes we know that. In this specific case you have nothing whatsoever to gain and only obfuscate the code by 50% bloat if you call `int()`. If you disagree, explain what you gain by unnecessarily calling `int()`?

Comment: @smci Extensiblity. In this example if you change `in range(1,6)` to `in range(1,len(products))` or as seen in my answer you can add as many items to the products list/dictionary and not have to edit the rest of the code. Keeping it as a string means you need to add all the choices to `in [..]` in your example. He is also treating it as an `int` in the OP, I think he left out the `int` call but the `input` call is wrapped in parens and he doesn't use quoted numbers anywhere in his code.

Comment: @smci as IanAuld points out, it's not that I'm casting to `int` to do a `range` check, that would be silly. I'm casting to `int` because the OP seems to use the choice as basis for an index which means it needs to be an `int` anyway. "Hey," the savvy programmer thinks to himself, "If it's already going to be a number, let's test it as one too!"

Comment: @IanAuld: yes I know about the extensibility, I was the first person to post a solution here and I was originally using `range()`. Look guys, I was simply showing the OP a practical fast-and-dirty check that results in nice tight code, vastly cuts down his example. I understand the 'look before you leap' caveats to exception-avoiding too. My aim here was compact and simple code.

Answer (score 1):

"A programmer once had a problem so he decided to use regex and now he has 2 problems" - A much wiser man then myself

What I would do:

```
products = {1 : ['Twix', 1], 2 : ['Freddo', 1.50]}  # use a dictionary as a pseudo DB  
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input(...))
        break
    except (ValueError, KeyError):  
    # ValueError exception will occur if a user enters an invlaid choice like a letter
    # KeyError will occur if the user enter a number that has no key, example if your keys are 1-5 and user enters a 7
        # handle error


print(products[choice])
```

Using the dictionary saves yourself the trouble of editing you code should you need to add more items to your vending machine. This code will work fine no matter how many items you add to the dictionary with out out the need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex here, you can simply say:

```
while True:
    choice = input("choice between 1-5: ")
    if choice in ['1','2','3','4','5']:
        break
    else:
        print("Not a valid value")
```

This is more compact and doesn't need to be surrounded with `try... except` block since it doesn't call `int()` and risk throwing ValueError per @Adam-Smith's answer. Ditto, whitespace or anything else that isn't a single digit.

And if you really want compact code:

```
    while True:
        choice = input("choice between 1-5: ")
        if choice in ['1','2','3','4','5']: break
        print("Not a valid value")
```

Comment: @Adam-Smith: but that will also wrongly accept '123' : '123' in '12345' is True

Comment: Clearly I didn't intend to call `int()` on it, since I explicitly wrote so, and keeping it string avoids that. Call to `int()` removed.